# PHP error in mysql database selection

Tags: php, mysqli

I wrote a code in PHP to connect with Mysql database and add data into it.. code is given below:

```
$dbhostname = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "rms_invoice";

function showDBMessage(){
    if($_POST["name"] != NULL){
        //came from register page
        if(register()){
            print("<br/>Registered successfully!!!");
        } else {
            print("<br/>Registration failed!!!");
        }
    }
}
function register(){
    global $dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword,$dbname;
    // Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect($dbhostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    // Check connection
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        print("MYSQL Connection established...<br/>");
        echo "<br/>Successful: ".mysqli_get_host_info($con);
        $selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname);
        if(false!==$selected){
            $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["name"]);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["password"]);
            $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["address"]);

            $insertUserQuery="INSERT INTO USER(name,username,password,address) VALUES ('$name','$username','$password','$address')";
            echo $insertUserQuery;
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $insertUserQuery);
            if ( false===$result ) {
                printf("<br/>mysqli_connect_error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                printf("<br/>mysqli_error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
            } else {
                echo "<h4>New User Added!!!</h4><br/>";
                return true;
            }
        }else{
            printf("<br/>Error while selecting database, error:%s\n",mysqli_errno($con));
        }
    } else {
        print("<br/>Failed to connect to MySQL: "+mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    return false;
}
```

and the output is:

```
MYSQL Connection established...
Successful: localhost via TCP/IP
INSERT INTO USER(name,username,password,address) VALUES ('nitin','ndthokare','p','beed')
mysqli_connect_error: 
mysqli_error: No database selected 
Registration failed!!!
```

It is getting connected but database selection seems to be problem. (same query executes successfully through `mysql cli`).

I tried many possible corrections in code discussed on SO, but could not succeed.

Can anybody help me to find out the mistake?

Comment: To be sure, "rms_invoice" *is* the correct database name, right?

Comment: Please read this - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Injecting values directly into your SQL statements is unsafe

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(false!==!$selected){
```

is extremely unusual operator (called "double negative") means you want to execute the following code block only if $selected is FALSE.
to make it much less confusing, write it without all these magic chants

```
 if($selected){
```

or even omit this useless check completely.

Comment: Hmm, I do agree the double NOT is a definite weird but in actual that `if` block _is_ getting executed, so this in itself cannot be the complete answer, maybe you should address more.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger The `if` block **is** being executed because `$selected` is `FALSE` meaning `mysqli_select_db` failed. This answer is completely correct

Comment: Ya.. that was actually mistake by overlook... I it was `if(false!==$selected)` or `if(true===!$selected)`...

Comment: but now the error is.. `MYSQL Connection established...
Successful: localhost via TCP/IP...
Error while selecting database, error:1046 ...
Registration failed!!!`

Comment: that's quite obvious and self-explained one